# In a .NET web app, how can I implement Membership without having to host my own SQL database?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-membership, amazon-web-services

I'm using Amazon Web Services for nearly everything, including their SimpleDB flat database. It's so nice, stable, reasonably safe, etc.. The moment I begin to add Membership to my web app in .NET, it feels like I have to start becoming a fully-fledged database administrator and backup and manage a SQL database.

Is there any method for implementing username/password/login/password recovery features on my website without having to host, backup and manage a SQL server myself?

Thank you!

---UPDATE----
Found this sample project on AWS that has the basic custom Memebership code. It's a great start:

http://aws.amazon.com/articles/3592

Comment: Write or find a SimpleDB Membership provider.

Comment: Thanks SLaks- I'm not that talented. Yet. One day.

Comment: I've never used AWS, so I can't give you any more advice (although Google might).  Note that you have the correct attitude here; secure design is _hard_.  For anything else, though (except multithreading), I would not recommend that attitude.  In general, try, see how far you get, and ask SO questions to cover the rest.  Thus is the road to true talent.  (I may turn this comment into a blog post)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By providing you own MembershipProvider you can abstract the data access.

There are two steps for this.

One. In web.config:

```
 <membership defaultProvider="MyMembershipProvider">
 <providers>
 <clear/>
 <add name="MyMembershipProvider" type="Full.Name.MyMembershipProvider" 
 more options here/>
 </providers>
 </membership>
```

Two. The membership class.

```
 public sealed class MyMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider {
    //... much more here 
    //example method:
    public override bool ChangePassword(string username, string oldPwd, string newPwd)
    {
        //access simpleDb here
    }
 }
```

The good news is that you have to implement only the methods you use, e.g. if you do registration through other channels then you can get away with only implementing *ChangePassword*, *ValidateUser* and *Initialize*.

Have a look at [How to: Sample Membership Provider Implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tc47t75.aspx) (for the class code)
and [Sample Membership Provider Implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/44w5aswa.aspx) (for the web.config bit).

Comment: Thanks Tymek- Those are great links. A little too challenging for me at this point, but I'll get there one day. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement custom membership provider. Take a look at MSDN article - [Implementing a Membership Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx) and an article - [Building Custom Providers for ASP.NET 2.0 Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479048.aspx).

Comment: Thanks AVD- Those are great links. Always amazed the breadth and depth of MSDN articles on any given topic.

Answer (score 0):

RSSBus provides a SimpleDB data provider (looks free for now):

http://www.rssbus.net/ado/amazon-simpledb/features.aspx

Comment: Thanks M. That's a great ADO style simpleDB wrapper. I wrote those guys and asked if they had any Membership implementation code- I'm not good enough to write my own membership provider (I'm in startup mode and am just trying to fly through boilerplate stuff).

Comment: The source code for the standard SqlMembershipProvider is freely available so you could use it as a starting place if it won't already do what you're after. Check out this blog post for details: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/13/442772.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

There's a sample asp.net app with the .net sdk that has a sample simpledb membership provider class (petboard sample) http://aws.amazon.com/articles/3592